# Duplicate roles programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

As the title said, I want to duplicate roles programmatically and especially I will call that action from frontend.

The problem here is I don't know which file contained the action I need to call. Damn Varien.

Any help will be appreciated, I'm very new to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Magento admin has roles and you want to invoke this from the frontend? You mean from the admin I'm guessing.

If you want to add a duplicate function in there you should take a look at the `core/Mage/Adminhtml/(controllers|Block)/Permissions` to start with.

You could create a custom module which extends these classes and add your own functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'll skip writing the extension part because there's plenty of resources for that, but the place you should start looking is `Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController::saveRoleAction()`. More specifically,

```
// For role
$roleName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('rolename', false);
$role->setName($roleName)
     ->setPid($this->getRequest()->getParam('parent_id', false))
     ->setRoleType('G');
...
$role->save();

// For permissions
$resource   = explode(',', $this->getRequest()->getParam('resource', false));
...
Mage::getModel("admin/rules")
    ->setRoleId($role->getId())
    ->setResources($resource)
    ->saveRel();
```

You'll see that `$resource` delineates the specific permissions, like `admin/page_cache,admin/dashboard,admin/sales,admin/sales/order...`. You can write your own controller and action that mimic this behavior, and you got your program!